# How can you list a directory using the inode not the directory name? I have the same directory name appearing twice with different inodes

Tags: directory, ls, inode, duplicate-files

When I do a directory listing of a python installation the `include` directory appears twice and each one has a different `inode`.

```
╰─○ ls -i1
2282047 bin
2641630 include
2642559 include 
2282048 lib
2641850 share
```

I assume that their contents may be different as the inodes are different.

Is there away to use the `ls` command to use the inode not the directory name so I can check them individually?

When I execute `ls include` I have no idea which directory is listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to have directories or files with duplicate names in Unix and so there would be no reason for `ls` to have an option to handle that use case.

The reason you are seeing what appears to be duplicates is because one directory actually has a trailing space (inode `2642559`).

BusyBox's `ls`, unlike GNU's `ls`, doesn't quote names of directories and files that have spaces so it can be easy to misinterpret them.

Comment: You are right. I thought `ls` quotes filenames when there are spaces in them. Perhaps the version on the Debian Stretch doesn't quote files names with spaces in them or requires an additional option.